# pointer to function in c code

Tags: c, pointers

i am very new in c programming. i am using a c code from the book 'numerical recipes in C' for polynomial regression. in this program i need to replace (*funcs) function with fpoly function.but i dont know how to do that and how to make changes in fpoly function to become like (*fpoly).could you please help me with that?

I really appreciate any help.

```
void fpoly(float x, float p[], int np)
//Fitting routine for a polynomial of degree np-1, with coefficients in the array p[1..np].
{
    int j;
    p[1]=1.0;
    for (j=2;j<=np;j++) p[j]=p[j-1]*x;
}



void lfit( float x[], float y[], float sig[], int ndat, float a[], int ia[], int ma, float **covar, float *chisq, void (*funcs)(float, float [], int))
```

and here is the complete program:

```
void lfit(float x[], float y[], float sig[], int ndat, float a[], int ia[],
      int ma, float **covar, float *chisq, void (*funcs) (float,float[],  int))

/*Given a set of data points x[1..ndat], y[1..ndat] with individual standard deviations
sig[1..ndat], use χ2 minimization to fit for some or all of the coefficients a[1..ma] of
a function that depends linearly on a, y =sum(i)( ai × afunci(x)). The input array ia[1..ma]
indicates by nonzero entries those components of a that should be fitted for, and by zero entries
those components that should be held fixed at their input values. The program returns values
for a[1..ma], χ2 = chisq, and the covariance matrix covar[1..ma][1..ma]. (Parameters
held fixed will return zero covariances.)Th e user supplies a routine funcs(x,afunc,ma) that
returns the ma basis functions evaluated at x = x in the array afunc[1..ma].*/
{

    void covsrt(float **covar, int ma, int ia[], int mfit);
    void gaussj(float **a, int n, float **b, int m);

    int i, j, k, l, m, mfit = 0;
    float ym, wt, sum, sig2i, **beta, *afunc;

    beta = matrix(1, ma, 1, 1);
    afunc = vector(1, ma);

    for (j = 1; j <= ma; j++)
        if (ia[j])
          mfit++;
    if (mfit == 0)
       nrerror("lfit: no parameters to be fitted");

    for (j = 1; j <= mfit; j++) {   //Initialize the (symmetric)mat rix.
        for (k = 1; k <= mfit; k++)
            covar[j][k] = 0.0;
        beta[j][1] = 0.0;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= ndat; i++) {
    (*funcs) (x[i], afunc, ma);
    ym = y[i];
    if (mfit < ma) {              //Subtract off dependences on known pieces
        for (j = 1; j <= ma; j++)     //of the fitting function.
        if (!ia[j])
            ym -= a[j] * afunc[j];
    }
    sig2i = 1.0 / SQR(sig[i]);
    for (j = 0, l = 1; l <= ma; l++) {
        if (ia[l]) {
        wt = afunc[l] * sig2i;
        for (j++, k = 0, m = 1; m <= l; m++)
            if (ia[m])
            covar[j][++k] += wt * afunc[m];
        beta[j][1] += ym * wt;
        }
    }
    }
    for (j = 2; j <= mfit; j++)      //Fill in above the diagonal from symmetry.
        for (k = 1; k < j; k++)
           covar[k][j] = covar[j][k];
    gaussj(covar, mfit, beta, 1);      //Matrix solution.
    for (j = 0, l = 1; l <= ma; l++)
         if (ia[l])
           a[l] = beta[++j][1];    //Partition solution to appropriate coefficients
    *chisq = 0.0;   

    for (i = 1; i <= ndat; i++) {      //Evaluate χ2 of the fit.
        (*funcs) (x[i], afunc, ma);
            for (sum = 0.0, j = 1; j <= ma; j++)
                sum += a[j] * afunc[j];
    *chisq += SQR((y[i] - sum) / sig[i]);
    }
    covsrt(covar, ma, ia, mfit);      //Sort covariance matrix to true order of fittin
    free_vector(afunc, 1, ma);    //coefficients.
    free_matrix(beta, 1, ma, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: This question is not clear enough. Your English is bad, so it's practically incomprehensible what you want. The code is not formatted  so it's very hard to read (not even understand, just read) it. Please consider improving both aspects.

Comment: actually i put the whole program just to help you to understand my question better, otherwise my main question is easy to understand i think.
my main function is 'lfit' which is calling another function '(*funcs)'. 'fpoly' function is something that i have added later to the function to define 'funcs'. but fpoly is equal to funcs not (*funcs).
now i dont know how to change fpoly to do the same thing as (*funcs).

Comment: the *func definition is used to indicate that this input parameter is an address to a function. see my answer for more details

Comment: Try to clarify your code man, It's very hard to read, and sometimes is better to use curly braces than none when you have several nested for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
void lfit( float [], float [], float [], int, float [], int [], int, float**, float*, void (*funcs)(float, float [], int))
```

"void (*funcs)(float, float [], int)" is the type signature of the function pointer.
If it is in-scope, you can just pass the name of your function (fpoly) in place of "void (*funcs)(float, float [], int)", without parentheses or anything. You can also take its address with the & operator but I believe it's equivalent:

```
lfit( all_the_other_args, ..., fpoly);
```

You could also have a local function pointer which holds fpoly:

```
void (*local_function_pointer_variable)(float, float [], int) = fpoly;
lfit( all_the_other_args, ..., local_function_pointer_variable);
```

In C the syntax of function pointer types is somehow inconvenient but hopefully you can define a type to hide this to some extent

```
typedef void (*poly_fitter)(float, float [], int);
poly_fitter function_pointer_var_of_type_poly_fitter = fpoly;
lfit( all_the_other_args, ..., function_pointer_var_of_type_poly_fitter)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass the function `poly` if so, then just pass the name of the function:

```
lfit(x, y,...., poly);
```

Answer (score 1):

the lfit function has many input parameter.

1 of the parameter is **address** to a function. and that's why we have added `*` in the definition of that input parameter.

```
void (*funcs) (float, float[], int))
```

so when you calling `lfit()` function you can mention the address the address of your `fpoly()` function as the input of your `lfit()` function

the address of `void fpoly(float x, float p[], int np)` is `fpoly` or `&fpoly`

so when you call your function `lfit()` you can do it in this way:

`lfit(x,y,...,fpoly)`

or in this way:

`lfit(x,y,...,&fpoly)`

Comment: thank you Mohamed, i used lfit(x,y,...,&fpoly). the program still shows some other errors, but i think the error related to this question solved :)